# Electrons and Holes in a semiconductor

Tags: semiconductors, electron, solid-state-devices

In an exercise I have an un-doped silicon I find that p=1.80e+11 ,n=6.60e+10 , should the numbers be more close to each other? (for example in GaAs I find 1.10e+14 and 1.60e+14)?? (also p number of holes and n number of electrons)

`T=300 Temperature in K
Nc=2.8*(10^19)  (density of states I guess in English)
Nv=1.04*(10^19)
Eg=1.12  eV Band Gap`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide more information. Undoped means there is no P or N type silicon. How did you get these figures?

Comment: Please explain your variables, everyone has different letters for different physical values

Comment: I used the type n=c exp[Ec-Ef] and p = Nv exp[Ev-Ef]

Comment: @laptop2d got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, concentrations of electrons and holes must obey the law of mass action (at equilibrium):

$$np=n_i^2$$

Your calculated values clearly violate this for silicon, therefore you can easily tell your calculation is wrong.

---

It's hard to know what approach an instructor asking this question would want you to follow. If someone asked me to answer this question, I would just write down the answer. If you don't know it off the top of your head, consider what \$n_i\$ represents. If you still don't know the answer or want to just use some basic equations, continue on.

---

The problem is easier than you are making it. All semiconductors in equilibrium follow the previous law, and also are charge neutral:

$$n + N_A^- = p + N_D^+$$

In an undoped semiconductor the acceptor and donor concentrations are both zero (by definition) and therefore you are left with:

$$n=p$$

Calculating the actual numbers is left as an exercise for the reader. (Hint: If you need a calculator, it's probably wrong)

Comment: Shouldn't these n=Nc exp[Ec-Ef] and p = Nv exp[Ev-Ef]  gave me the correct numbers?

Comment: @Stavros I don't remember exactly what assumptions go into the derivation of those equations, but they are an approximation. They "should" probably give you the right answer, but clearly they didnt this time (although I didnt check your math) Note that for an intrinsic semiconductor n and p should be exactly the same, not just pretty close.

Comment: @Stavros Also, how do you know what the Fermi level is? It is not accurate to assume it is at midgap (That can sometimes be a reasonable approximation for Si. This is not one of those cases)

Comment: It states that  Ec - Ef = Egap/2, (also Python did my math)

Comment: @Stavros Then it is wrong. That is only true if Nc=Nv, which is not the case for Si or any other semiconductor I can think of.

Comment: Then, I have no Idea how I should calculate those...

Comment: @Stavros Which part? I have given you two equations. Solve that system of equations to get the answer. (the first and last equations)

Comment: you mean mass action law and n=p??

Comment: Yes. Technically this question is even easier that I made it, but the alternative was just stating the answer, and thats not educational.

Comment: so I use ni = sqrt(Nv*Nc) exp[Eg/2kt] that should work, I got your point

Comment: @Stavros Oh. I assumed you knew what ni in silicon was (you should memorize the value. It comes up a lot.) But yes.

Comment: Well exercise gives all these numbers about, Nc Nv etc so I asumed I should use those :P

Comment: @Stavros Its a weird exercise then. This question doesn't require any math if you have the value of ni memorized. (ni for Si: 10^10 cm^-3 at room temp)

Comment: Also mass action law is stated later but since it works...:)

Comment: @Stavros With questions like this its hard to tell what approach they want you to take. This might have been more of a definition question. ni is the intrinsic carrier concentration. It literally is the concentration of electrons and holes in an intrinsic (undoped) semiconductor.